# how to upload image to another location with server

Tags: laravel-8

public function uploadImage(Request $request){

```
    $resultError = "";
    $resultMsg = "";
    $resultData = "";
    try {

        $file = "";
        $imgFile = $request->file('sign_input');

        if ($imgFile != '') {
             $file= $imgFile->getClientOriginalName();
             //$filePath = public_path('/assets/uploads/sign/');
             $destinationPath = 'https://mylink/share.cgi?ssid=3d00570fc7574803a3abef77c39f4847&func=upload&type=standard&dest_path=/&overwrite=2&progress=image.png';

             $dest = "https://mylink/share.cgi?ssid=3d00570fc7574803a3abef77c39f4847#3d00570fc7574803a3abef77c39f4847";                 
             $imgFile->move($dest, $file);
             $destFile = "https://mylink/share.cgi?ssid=3d00570fc7574803a3abef77c39f4847#3d00570fc7574803a3abef77c39f4847".$file;


            // Http::attach('attachment', file_get_contents($image), 'image.png')
            // ->post('mylink/share.cgi?   ssid=3d00570fc7574803a3abef77c39f4847&func=upload&type=standard&dest_path=/&overwrite=2&progress=image.png', $request->all());
        } else {
            $file = "";
        }            
       
        if($file == false) {
            $resultMsg = "Save Failure!";
            $resultError = "true";
        } else {
            $resultMsg = "Save Success!";
            $resultError = "false";
            $resultData = $file;
        }
    
    } catch (Exception $e) {
   
            $resultMsg = $e;
            $resultError = "true";
    }
    return json_encode(compact('resultMsg', 'resultError', 'resultData'));

}
```

Symfony \ Component\ HttpFoundation\ File\ Exception\ FileException

Unable to create the "https://mylink/share.cgi?ssid=3d00570fc7574803a3abef77c39f4847#3d00570fc7574803a3abef77c39f4847" directory.